# HTML division not responsive in smaller screen

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm currently developing this form for my company, I had a problem in creating the responsive site of the form.
Im using bootstrap framework to design it.

For the code portion below, when i open it in mobile phone, the row does not stack to each other, instead it just become squeezed. Can I know how to make it stack onto each other ?

thanks

Code in HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="" class="row-fluid">
    <fieldset class="row-fluid">
            <legend>Your Project</legend>
            <label>Choose the services you want</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12">
                    <div class="span3" style="text-align:center;">
                            <label for="SEO" class="checkbox inline">
                                <input class="block-level-input" id="seo" name="seo" type="checkbox" onClick="optionCheck1()" value='TRUE' />SEO</label>

                            <select class="input-xlarge" id="seoCost" name="seoCost" style="visibility:hidden;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" onChange='customBox1(this.value)'>
                                    <option value="0">Select Cost </option>
                                    <option value="600">$600</option>
                                    <option value="800">$800</option>
                                    <option value="1000">$1000</option>
                                    <option value="custom">Custom</option>
                            </select>

                            <input class="input-xlarge" id="customCost1" name="customCost1"  type="number" value="0" style="display:none;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"/>


                            <div id="seodr" class="block-level-input" style="display:none;">
                                    <label>Duration of Service</label>
                                    <select class="input-xlarge" id="seoduration" name="seoduration" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                                        <option value="0">Select Duration</option>
                                        <option value="1">1 month</option>
                                        <option value="2">2 month</option>
                                        <option value="3">3 month</option>
                                        <option value="4">4 month</option>
                                        <option value="5">5 month</option>
                                        <option value="6">6 month</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="span3">
                        <label for="edm" class="checkbox inline">
                            <input class="block-level-input" id="edm" name="edm" type="checkbox" onClick="edmCheck()" value='TRUE' />EDM</label>
                        <select class="input-xlarge" id="edmCost" name="edmCost" style="visibility:hidden; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" >
                            <option value="0">Select Cost </option>
                            <option value="450">$450</option>
                            <option value="550">$550</option>
                            <option value="650">$650</option>
                        </select>

                        <div id="edmqty" class="row-fluid" style="display:none;">
                            <label>Quantity</label>
                            <select class="input-xlarge" id="edmquantity" name="edmquantity" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" >
                                <option value="0">Select</option>
                                <option value="1">1 </option>
                                <option value="2">2 </option>
                                <option value="3">3 </option>
                                <option value="4">4 </option>
                                <option value="5">5 </option>
                                <option value="6">6 </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>  

                    <div class="span3">
                        <label for="sem" class="checkbox inline">   
                            <input class="block-level-input" id="sem" name="sem" type="checkbox" onClick="semCheck()" value='TRUE' />SEM</label>

                        <select class="input-xlarge" id="semCost" name="semCost" style="visibility:hidden; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                            <option value="0">Select Cost </option>
                            <option value="500">$500</option>
                            <option value="600">$600</option>
                            <option value="700">$700</option>
                        </select>

                        <div id="semdr" class="row-fluid" style="display:none;">
                            <label>Duration of service</label>
                            <select class="input-xlarge" id="semduration" name="semduration" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" >
                                <option value="0">Select</option>
                                <option value="1">1 month </option>
                                <option value="2">2 months</option>
                                <option value="3">3 months</option>
                                <option value="4">4 months</option>
                                <option value="5">5 months</option>
                                <option value="6">6 months</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="span3">
                        <label for="smm" class="checkbox inline">   
                            <input class="block-level-input" id="smm" name="smm" type="checkbox" onClick="smmCheck()" value='TRUE' />SMM</label>

                        <select class="input-xlarge" id="smmCost" name="smmCost" style="visibility:hidden; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                            <option value="0">Select Cost </option>
                            <option value="500">$500</option>
                            <option value="600">$600</option>
                            <option value="700">$700</option>
                        </select>

                        <div id="smmdr" class="row-fluid" style="display:none;">
                            <label>Duration of service</label>
                            <select class="input-xlarge" id="smmduration" name="smmduration" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" >
                                <option value="0">Select</option>
                                <option value="1">1 month </option>
                                <option value="2">2 months</option>
                                <option value="3">3 months</option>
                                <option value="4">4 months</option>
                                <option value="5">5 months</option>
                                <option value="6">6 months</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
            </form>
</div>
```

Sorry if it seems simple, new to coding here.

thanks

Comment: Can you show us your CSS too?

Comment: Im using bootstrap-resposive css fully, no additional one

Comment: The CSS defines the styling of the HTML markup - that is, the stacking or squeezing behavior.  So, without access to the CSS, I predict it will be difficult to change this.  Hopefully I'm wrong or misunderstand your question :)

Comment: @Steve Actually all that's done in the bootstrap CSS, you just put the classes on your elements: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using bootstrap responsive CSS and not the standard CSS.

Then get rid of the min-width on your containing element `container-fluid`. It's not fluid at mobile size if it has a fixed min-width. Then replace your `row` classes with `row-fluid` classes.

Comment: what i put in the head section is :
link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

all no min-width used as well

Comment: Ok solved it alr, just need to make sure i dont give class for the fieldset and form